# How to use third-party library (gridstack.js) with Typescript and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Maybe I'm missing some fundamental concepts of Typescript and/or React, but I can't make the following to work:

1. I'm using a [React/Typescript Boilerplate](https://github.com/barbar/vortigern) as my app template. (No problems here).
2. In the other hand, I'm using a plain JS library called [GridStack.js](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) that extends jQuery with `$.fn.gridstack(options)`. When you import this library into a simple HTML page you just need to initialize it by calling `$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options)`. (Still no problems).
3. Then **my objective is to create a TypeScript/React wrapper for gridstack.js than can be used in my boilerplate**. This is where I have problems. I'm a bit lost between typescript and react, I even found a [wrapper for React](https://github.com/pitrho/react-gridstack) and also [Gridstack.js typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gridstack) but I can't make everything work together. This is why I decided to try to create my own wrapper but still without success. Specially where to import either `react-gridstack` or `gridstack` to make it work.

Can someone explain what am I missing? This is my code so far:

***gridstackWrapper.tsx***:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export default class extends React.Component {
    public shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public componentDidMount() {
        $(this.refs.gridstack).addClass('a-new-class');  // THIS WORKS

        // ERROR: TypeError: $(...).gridstack is not a function
        // So basically $.fn.gridstack(options) is not working
        $(this.refs.gridstack).gridstack(this.gridstackOptions);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div ref="gridstack" className="grid-stack" />
        );
    }

    private gridstackOptions = {
        float: false,
        animate: true,
        resizable: {handles: 'se, sw'},
        verticalMargin: 12,
        placeholderText: 'Move Control Here',
        minWidth: 767,
    };
}
```

***index.tsx***:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import GridstackWrapper from './gridstackWrapper';

class About extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <GridstackWrapper />
    );
  }
}

export { About }
```

***package.json***:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/gridstack": "0.0.38",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.12",
    "@types/jqueryui": "1.11.36",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.74",
}
"dependencies": {
    "gridstack": "0.3.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4"
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated, especially if I'm missing any fundamental concepts about React and Typescript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added `webpack` tag since this appears to be a webpack bundling question (the error was at run time, not compile time).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the type definitions for gridstack.

Run `npm install --save-dev @types/gridstack`.

This will install the `.d.ts` files from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/gridstack).

Comment: Thanks! I already did, I edited my question to show how my package.json (partially) looks like.

Comment: Run time! Of course it would work if I just include gridstack.min.js manually as an HTML script, but I want it to be packed into bundle.js

Comment: So this question is actually not related to any of your tags. Its a bundling question. Which bundler are you using? Please add the config to your question.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's webpack, I used the one from the boilerplate, it's easier to check it on this link: https://github.com/barbar/vortigern/blob/develop/config/webpack/dev.js
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, I don't know much about webpack. I switched [my boilerplate](https://github.com/styfle/react-server-example-tsx)  to webpack recently and used [externals](https://github.com/styfle/react-server-example-tsx/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L31) to tell webpack to not bundle an imported module. Did you try just `import * as g from './gridstack.js'`?